# Chern's definition of G-structure

Tags: differential-geometry

Section 4, page 10 of [The geometry of G-structures](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-72/issue-2/The-geometry-of-G-structures/bams/1183527777.full) by S. S. Chern,  Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 72(2): 167-219 (March 1966), the definition of G-structure is somewhat vague, and I have have the impression that it is wrong.

> Let $T$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and let $T^*$ be its dual space. Denote their pairing by $\langle y, \xi \rangle \in R$, $y \in T$, $\xi \in T^*$. We let $GL(n,R)$ act on $T$ on the left and on $T^*$ on the right, so that the following relation holds:
>
> $$\langle gy, \xi \rangle = \langle y, \xi g \rangle, \quad \quad g \in GL(n,R).$$
>
> The tangent bundle over $M$ has the local charts $(x,y_U)$, $x \in U$, $y_U \in T$, which are the local coordinates of the tangent vectors relative to $U$. The local coordinates $(x, y_U)$ and $(x, y_V)$ in $U \cap V$ define the same tangent vector if and only if $y_U = g_{UV}(x)y_V$, where $g_{UV} : U \cap V \to GL(n,R)$. Consider a subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,R)$; we say that the structural gropu of the tangent bundle is reduced to $G$, if all $g_{UV}(x) \in G$. Such a reduction will simply be called a $G$-structure.

I cannot relate this definition to other ones found elsewhere (using the notion of principal G-bundles). Is it complete? Correct? What am I missing?

The article by Chern is in the reference list of Wikipedia's article  [G-Structures on a manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-structure_on_a_manifold)

Comment: Could you say why you think this is wrong? Do you know a definition that you believe to be correct?

Comment: @Deane I was thinking of Wikipedia's, though I find it quite unclear too.

Comment: Yes, Chern is right. See also the book by Kobayashi and Nomizu.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks. I still don't see that it works, but I may be using a wrong definition of what he meant by "local coordinates $(x,y_U)$".

Comment: @Arnaud: How do you give local coordinates on the tangent bundle? Here he is working with trivializations over the open sets $U$ and $V$ and relating them.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. There are many ways one could locally trivialize the tangent bundle, since it amounts to choosing a frame on every tangent space. The most natural ones are via the differential of a chart U -> R^n. Does he consider those ones?

Comment: That's the standard approach, although not the only possibility.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK but that "natural" choice can't be what Chern uses as trivializations, so what does he mean?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you be more precise? I have know the definition of fiber bundles for maybe 25 years and used it a few times in the past, though I never looked at elaborated notions beyond the definition and basic examples like tangent bundle, cotangent bundle, tensors, exterior, etc.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for your patience and work.

Comment: Indeed, Chern is being sloppy when he refers to local coordinates on the tangent bundle. He does not make clear that, on one hand, he is not referring to the standard coordinates induced by the coordinates on the manifold, but on the other hand, he is assuming that the coordinates are linear with respect to the vector space structure of a fiber of the tangent bundle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chern's definition is a little sloppy. His phrasing here gives the impression that reduction of the structure group is a property of $M$, which it's not; reductions need not be unique if they exist. You can see that reflected implicitly here by the fact that local coordinates and hence transition functions are highly non-unique. It's also a bit confusing that even if reductions exist in some coordinates they may not be witnessed by a generic choice of coordinates.

To fix it one can say that a choice of reduction of the structure group is a choice of local coordinates such that the transition functions lie in $G$; up to isomorphism this agrees with the usual definition in terms of $G$-bundles, although the $G$-bundle definition is more general because the map $G \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ need not be injective (e.g. $G$ might be the spin group $\text{Spin}(n)$).

Comment: Thanks. With your help and @TedShifrin 's questions I finally understood what Chern meant. He is certainly not using the canonical charts of the tangent bundle, but instead choosing a set of "vector bundle charts" of it with the property. This choice of such an atlas modulo the usual compatibility "union of two such atlases is such an atlas" fixes the G-structure.

Answer (score 2):

I validated the answer of Qiaochu Yuan as the accepted answer because it helped me recover what is implicitly meant in the quoted text.

I add this answer as a detailed explanation of the source of confusion, I think it can help other people.

1. When Chern wrote

> The tangent bundle over $M$ has the local charts $(x,y_U)$, $x∈U$, $y_U∈T$, which are the local coordinates of the tangent vectors relative to $U$.

I thought he meant *canonical charts of the tangent bundle*, i.e. charts that are associated to a diffeomorphism $\phi: U\to U'\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and where $(x,v)$, $x\in M$, $v\in T_x M$ is mapped to $(\phi(x),(D_x\phi)(v))\in \phi(U)\times \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that the action of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ introduced at the beginning yields an identification from $T$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\phi$ allows to identify $U$ and $U'$, so we can identify $U'\times \mathbb{R}^n$ with $U\times T$.

With this belief, the definition looked wrong: for instance Riemannian metrics are supposed to correspond to $G=O(2)$. Take the unit Euclidean sphere centred on $0$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced Riemannian metric. With this belief, $g_{UV}$ is the composition of the differential of two manifold charts.
Consider two charts on, for instance $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y)$ when $z>0$ and $(x,y,z)\mapsto(y,z)$ when $x>0$. The change of charts is $(x,y)\mapsto(y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$, and its differential at $(x,y)$ does not belong to $O(2)\subset GL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Still with this belief, a way to fix it would be to ask that on every canonical chart one chooses for all $x\in U$ a frame $f_{U}(x): \mathbb{R}^n \to T$, with the compatibility condition
$$ f_{V,x}^{-1} \circ g_{UV}(x) \circ f_{U,x} \in  G . $$

2. However, what he actually meant is a *vector bundle chart*, in the sense of [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Transition_functions).

This may sound even more confusing before one understands that he is not allowing us to take all vector bundle charts. If he would, then the discussion above would still apply, just worse.

Actually he meant to define a $G$-structure via a special atlas on the tangent bundle seen as a general vector bundle, such that the transition maps between fibres belong to $G$; this is the spirit of $G$-bundles, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle#Structure_groups_and_transition_functions). This is called a $G$-atlas. This is in the spirit of the difference between topological manifold, smooth manifold, complex manifold, etc., where one asks transition maps to belong to different classes. In particular, here, two $G$-atlases are said to define the same $G$-structure whenever they are compatible, and this is equivalent to say that their union is still a $G$-atlas.

3. I will end this description by relating it to another definition of $G$-structure that I recomposed by reading various sources.

Given a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, and a subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,R)$ (*), a $G$-structure is the choice for each $x\in M$ of a subset $F_x$ of the set $\cal F(\mathbb{R}^n,T_x M)$ of frames $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to T_x M$ ($f$ bijective linear map) with the condition that $F_x$ is a whole and single orbit under the action of $G$ on $\cal F(\mathbb{R}^n,T_x M)$ by right-multiplication (pre-composition) by $g\in G$.

Continuity/smoothness conditions can be added.

(*) Often $G$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL(n,R)$; on the other hand, one can generalize the notion where $G$ is any group and were we take a group morphism from $G$ to $GL(n,R)$

The relation is as follows: the set $F_x$ is of the form $f G = \{f \circ g; f\in \cal F(\mathbb{R}^n,T_x M),\, g\in G\}$ where $f$ is not unique (it can be replaced by any $f\circ g$). One can locally *choose* a particular $f$ for every $x$, in a continuous/smooth fashion and this defines a local trivialization (vector bundle chart) of the tangent bundle, and those trivializations satisfy Chern's condition.

> $g_{UV}(x) \in G$

TL;DR

Chern is not using canonical charts of the tangent bundle but defining a $G$-structure as a $G$-atlas in the sense of [$G$-bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle#Structure_groups_and_transition_functions).